# Proposed tag merge: ancient rome & roman empire

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

what about merging these tags?

- ancient-rome + roman-empire

Comment: Possible, but I can think of instances where there may be questions about ancient-rome that is not about the roman-empire.  Do you have a good rationale for doing so?

Comment: Roman kingdom and republic would also be covered under ancient-rome.

Comment: I think this needs to be done (I was going to propose cleanup of rome-related tags) but my concerns are that roman empire may cover Qs both for late-ancient-rome (e.g. Ceasars) and Holy Roman Empire. There's also "rome" tag.

Comment: I'd go with ancient-rome covering actual ancient Rome (be it the kingdom, the republic and the empire), ignoring the Holy Roman Empire that is completely unrelated except for the name.

Comment: The tags, if merged, cover a lot of time that someone that was looking for say, the Roman Republic (which would fall under ancient Rome) would have to sif through a lot of unrelated questions. Merging medivial and middle-ages might have a better case.

Comment: I've just forked the Medieval / Middle Ages request into [its own question](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tag-merge-request-middle-ages-and-medieval). I would propose an edit to this question to remove the duplication, but I appear not to be able to do so on meta ;o)