# Tag merge request: Middle Ages and Medieval

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[middle-ages](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-ages) and [medieval](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) seem like obvious duplicates, to me. This was brought up in [#143: Proposed tag merge](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/143/659), but that's become sidetracked by the discussion about the other two tags in that question, so I figured it makes sense to fork this discussion out from it.

I've just submitted a proposal for tag wiki content for [middle-ages](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-ages), so I'd prefer that that end up being the merge target, with [medieval](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) (a spelling that is different between varieties of English, in any case) be the synonym, but I guess that's unimportant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags have now been merged, with middle ages being the target. Medieval will now redirect to middle ages.

Comment: Thank you; I think that's very helpful :o)

Answer (score 2):

I second the request and think the OPs reasons for the request are on point. I can't think of a compelling reason to have the two tags separate.